# Database connections not being closed with jpaFlowExecutionListener

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I'm using Spring Web Flow to build an application. I am making use of the `Flow Managed Persistence Context` so the entity manager is 'kept open' during the execution of my flow and I can access lazy loaded properties (similar to `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` or `OpenSessionInViewFilter` for Spring MVC). When I use this, every time I submit a form, the number of active database connections increases, if I don't use the FMPC, I have no problems with the number of open connections).

I'm working with the following setup.

*TransactionManager*:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
}
```

*DataSource*:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_DATABASE_DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_DATABASE_URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_DATABASE_USERNAME, ""));
    dataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty(PROPERTY_DATABASE_PASSWORD, ""));
    return dataSource;
}
```

*EntityManagerFactory*:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

    final JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() {
        {
            setDatabase(Database.valueOf(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_DATABASE_TYPE)));
            setDatabasePlatform(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        }
    };
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    final Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_NAMING_STRATEGY));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
    jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_HB2DDL_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_HIBERNATE_HB2DDL_SQL));

    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

    return factoryBean;
}
```

*JpaFlowExecutionListener*:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public JpaFlowExecutionListener jpaFlowExecutionListener(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, JpaTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new JpaFlowExecutionListener(entityManagerFactory, transactionManager);
}
```

The `BasicDataSource` has `maxActive` set to **8** by default and when I reach 8 active connections, the page just hangs. Why are the connections not being closed after the request is complete? I have used the Chrome debugging tools (the network pane) to make sure there are not AJAX requests running or anything, my page submit (an HTTP POST) triggers a 301 redirect which then gives me a new HTTP GET and that results in a status 200, so all good.

When going from one page to the next, a service layer is called but as you can see from my beans, I am using the `JpaTransactionManager` and the SWF documentation says the following:

> - Note: All data access except for the final commit will, by default, be non-transactional. However, a flow may call into a transactional service layer to fetch objects during the conversation in the context of a read-only system transaction if the underlying JPA Transaction Manager supports this. Spring's JPA TransactionManager does support this when working with a Hibernate JPA provider, for example. In that case, Spring will handle setting the FlushMode to MANUAL to ensure any in-progress changes to managed persistent entities are not flushed, while reads of new objects occur transactionally.

For the sake of completeness, my spring-web-flow config:

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd">

    <!-- Flow executor, repsonsible for creating and executing flows -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="jpaFlowExecutionListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- Flow registry, responsible for loading all flows so executor can execute them -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/webflow/flows" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml"/>
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Flow builder services -->
    <webflow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="mvcViewFactoryCreator"/>

    <!-- MvcViewFactoryCreator -->
    <bean id="mvcViewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <ref bean="viewResolver"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Flow handler adapter, responsible for answering request for a flow -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Flow handler mapping, lets Spring MVCs DispatcherServlet know to send flow request to SWF -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry"/>
        <property name="order" value="0"/>
        <property name="interceptors">
            <list>
                <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

My flow has `<persistence-context />` defined at the top.

I have the following end-state (which restarts the flow), even when I invoke this and the URL params change to `e2s1`, the number of active connections is not reset:

```
<end-state id="restart" commit="true" view="redirect:/main"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the default hibernate property for `hibernate.connection.release_mode` is `on_close`. Considering the EntityManager is kept open during the whole flow, it never closes and a new connection is fetched from the pool for every request within the flow.

Changing the property to `after_transaction` solves this issue. However, in the case of fetching lazily loaded collections, it still doesn't work, each lazy property will fetch a new connection from the pool. In order to solve this I extended the `JpaFlowExecutionListener` with this:

```
public class AvoidLeakJpaFlowExecutionListener extends JpaFlowExecutionListener {

    public AvoidLeakJpaFlowExecutionListener(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
        super(entityManagerFactory, transactionManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void paused(RequestContext context) {
        super.paused(context);
        EntityManager entityManager = (EntityManager) context.getFlowScope().get(PERSISTENCE_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE);
        if (entityManager != null && entityManager instanceof HibernateEntityManager) {
            HibernateEntityManager hibernateEntityManager = (HibernateEntityManager) entityManager;
            hibernateEntityManager.getSession().disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

This approach solves the lazily loaded collections problem but will still leak connections *when loading of lazy-initialized entities is done using WebFlow's persistence context and this loading is performed during the transition to subflow that does not have  configured.* as described in [in this bug report](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWF-1525) (where I found this solution as well).

Comment: I had this issue recently as well and eventually gave up on it and ensured everything I needed to be loaded for the flow was loaded on flow start.